# Python: Converting column headers into single column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I got a dataframe which looks like

```
  Fever   Chill   Cough   Headache  Respiratory   Nasal   Joint Pain    Back pain   Stomach pain        
0   Y       Y        Y     NaN           NaN         NaN    NaN          NaN        NaN 
1   Y       NaN      NaN    NaN          Y           NaN    NaN          NaN        NaN 
2   Y       NaN       Y     NaN          NaN         NaN    NaN          NaN        NaN 
3   Y       NaN      NaN    NaN          NaN         NaN    Y            NaN        NaN 
4   Y       NaN      NaN    NaN          NaN         NaN    NaN          NaN        NaN
```

I want to convert columns header into single column (let say symptom) in such a way that newly column contains the column header name when it has value Y. Desired column should be look like:

```
      Symptom
0     Fever, Chill, Cough
1     Fever, Respiratory
2     Fever, Cough
3     Fever, Joint Pain
4     Fever
```

I used the concept of stack, but it didnt produce the desired ouput. Here is my code:

```
df[['Fever','Chill','Cough','Headache','Respiratory symptom','Nasal Symptoms','Joint Pain','Back pain','Stomach pain','Diarrhoea','Vomiting','Fatigue','Pneumonia shadow']].stack().reset_index()
```

Could anyone guide me how to get the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do `dot`

```
df.eq('Y').dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1]
#df['symptom'] = df.eq('Y').dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1]
```